# Strange Maintenance Plan SubPlans behaviour: each SP runs all the tasks of all other SP at odd times

Tags: sql-server-2005, maintenance

SQL Server 2005: I have a problem with scheduling a Maintenance Plan (MP) with 3 subplans (SP).

```
SP1 is scheduled to run hourly, 
SP2 daily at 7.00 and 
SP3 on sundays at 8.00
```

Reading MP history I see that what happened (I know it seems crazy) is:

```
11: SP1 runs and executes all the tasks of SP1 SP2 and SP3
12: SP2 runs and does the same
13: SP3 runs and does the same
14: SP1 runs and does the same
```

From the job Activity monitor, SP1 has last run time at 14, SP2 and SP3 are *never* been executed.
All of the SP are scheduled correctly in the Job Activity Monitor (SP2 for tomorrow at 7, SP3 for next sunday at 8)

Do you have any idea what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tries I found the reason for this behaviour.
I had set the property Disable of each SP to "False" instead of the default "True" and this causes the execution of all the SPs when just one is invoked.